# Selenium unable to find an element with input_type=file

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to upload a file using selenium `webdriver`, the problem is that the button to upload the file has an `input_type=file`.
I used `xpath`, `name`, `ID`, with `sendkeys` and it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='repondants_file']")).sendkeys("filepath");
```

I have also used JS:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='repondants_file']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",element );
```

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='repondants_file']}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:43)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:476)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
at TestPackage.OperationProjet2.main(OperationProjet2.java:41)
```

Here is the Html source code:

```
a href="http://test.360-feedback-enligne.fr/professionnel-rh/app/batch/encode.php" download="liste_repondants.xlsx">
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Importez le fichier EXCEL des répondants (conforme à la trame) :</label>
<input id="repondants_file" name="repondants_file" type="file"/>
```

Any clues?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? what happens when you try this code? any exceptions?

Comment: The code is expected to upload a file but nothing happens when executing  it, and I got the following error on my console: *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='repondants_file']}
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: This is not the complete stacktrace. Does it say `NoSuchElementException` by any chance? you should also add the relevant html to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can help you to click on the particular webelement which opens the windows file selector. Selenium won't be able to help you directly to select a file from your local directory structure. In that case you have to take help of Auto IT in your Selenium/Java code to select the particular file and then through Webdriver instance you can click on upload button to upload the selected file.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I have installed AutoIT, prepared its script, and modified my code as per below:                                                                                                       //Click repondants_file
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("repondants_file"));
            element.click();
      //Call AutoIT
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\za\\Desktop\\FileUpload.exe");

Comment: still getting the same stacktrace  :(

Comment: well as I am still getting the same stachtrace  error, it couldn't even call the AutoIT script, so I am still stuck my initial question which is Selenium not being able to find an element with input_type=file

Comment: It essentially means that the xpath you provided is not working. Can you update your question with the complete HTML DOM so that we can help you?

Comment: Use this xpath "//input[@id='repondants_file']" and let me know if the file selector box opens.

Comment: Or else try this xpath "//input [*id='repondants_file']" and update me.

Comment: Imo, you were trying to pass the windows file path in the file input field. I would rather suggest you to click on the "Browse" button next to the file input field so the windows file selector comes up for selecting the file from your windows file system. In that case you need to find the id/name/xpath of the Browse button & open the windows file selector. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Neither the ID, Name , Xpath allowed me to find the button...into my 3rd comment I have already changed the xpath to ID  and still not working

Comment: @AhmedKammoun what do you mean by "neither allowed me to find the button" ? The file picker (Browse) button must be beside the file text area on the webpage. The Browse button will be defined somewhere below the code you have pasted in the question. Can you provide a snapshot of the webpage? Provide some more of the HTML DOM & Update your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the required file using Selenium Webdriver with the help of **type** property of the control, as shown below:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendkeys("filepath");
```

Replace **filepath** in above code with the actual file path. Let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: IT's ok guys I have found the solution, I have used ExpectedConditions  as per below ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("repondants_file")));

Answer (score 0):

IT's ok guys I have found the solution, I have used ExpectedConditions as per below ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("reponda‌​nts_file")));